# How to direct user to search results after login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a simple app for allowing users to commit to meet ups. They can search for local meet ups without logging in, but will be directed to the login page. Is there a way to direct the user to their search results after successfully logging in?

I’m currently using passport.

So far I have not tried much because I am used to using..

```
res.redirect(‘back’);
```

But this project requires the user to not have to re-search once logged in.

Comment: I typically handle the redirect on the front-end.    Typically I authenticate with server on login, set a bunch of properties on the User object and use `window.location='/some-url'` to redirect the user.    Typically, `res.redirect()` is used in middleware to handle 404 errors.

Comment: I could see this working for me. The only issue is I would somehow have to keep track of search terms to the redirect. Like have the user search -> login -> render search page based on the API results.

Comment: @CollinDeSoto Which front-end framework are you using for this purpose?

Comment: @Ayan I’m actually not using one at all.

Comment: @CollinDeSoto Okay.You said that they can search for local meet ups without logging in.So when should the user be directed to the login page?Once the user tries to open any of the serach results?

Comment: @Ayan They get redirected right as they click the submit button on the search form. It then goes through middleware and redirects to ‘/login’

Comment: I would store the search terms in Local Storage and populate them in input, that way they are saved and will stick between pages.    Depends on the app and the UX you're going for.

Comment: What I did was store the users input within sessionStorage ONLY if there is not a current user. It then redirects to login. On successful login, the user is redirected to the search page which checks if(sessionStorage(“searchTerms”) if that is the case, it auto populates the form and submits it. I then clear the sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have much code in the question to look at I will try to answer with a few different scenarios you could achieve this. This is general strategy and can apply to any web stack and not just node.js and express. Hope it helps.

**Login Form, on same page as the search results:**

1. If you have all parameters you need to re-create the search in the URL like `something.com/search/searchterm` or `something.com?query=searchterm`, then when user is logging in , pass in the url as a POST parameter along with the login parameters. Then when user signs in, you can use `res.redirect(search_url);`
2. If from your search page URL you cannot re-create search result just form the URL, then you  need to have the search parameter. In this case during the login POST request, pass the search query as POST parameter. After successful login you can redirect again to search page with search query as a url parameter like `something.com?query=searchterm`. You can then use on-page javascript to perform your search again by reading the `query` parameter.

**Login Page different from the search page**

In this case before you can apply the two scenarios you need to save the search URL or parameter before you send user the login page. Now you can pass around parameters like in first scenario but that becomes complex quickly in a multi-hop scenario. In this case you can drop a **session cookie** with the search url or parameter with an indicator that redirect is needed after login. You can now use the information in the session after successful login to redirect use using any of the first two strategies.

**If you backend is web-services only**

Then chances are your app is a Single Page app with multiple routes like an Angular application backed by web-services. In this case you can also apply the same strategy as before but, instead of going with sessions just write the same information to **HTML5 Local Storage** before login. After Login, just use the information in storage to re-create the search page.

Answer (score 0):

When the non-logged in user does a search,you can **save the search parameters in the local storage** and redirect user to login page.

Now when the user lands to the redirected page after logging in,**check for the search parameters in the local storage**,and update your search results accordingly.Then **clear the search parameters from the local storage**,so that when the user logs in next time without having searched for anything,he doesn't get the previous search results.